# Altering a page from a Greasemonkey script whenever a specific <option> is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

While writing a GreaseMonkey script using jQuery and "tamtam", a question arose in my mind.

There is a page (which I can't edit) having a `<select>` element with four options. Option 2 is preselected.

```
<select id="idname" name="namename">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option selected="selected">Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
</select>
```

Now I'd like to call the script when Option1 is selected. Option1 leads to another site I want to insert my script.

How would I write something like:

```
if (Option1 is selected) {
    perform the script
}
```

Would something like the following work?

```
if(document.getElementById("idname").getElementsByTagName("option")[0].onselect == true){
    perform the script 
}
```

If not, can you post a reference helping me?

**Edit**

I was able to create a function and an event handler.

```
function myCompute(Event) {
    with (this) {  
        var myTest = value;

        if (value == "option1") {
            $("#tabelle").show();
        }

        else {
            $("#tabelle").hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Event handlers:

```
$("#option-type").change (myCompute);
$("#tabelle").hide();
```

It works as follows:
By choosing option 2,3 or 4 the table is hidden. By choosing option 1 the table is shown.
By visiting the site option 2 is selected most of the time and nothing is shown.
Now I got the case that option 1 is selected by visiting the site and no table appears, too. My idea was that the table should be shown when option1 is preselected.. I think that an EventHandler is missing.
Like you, Brock Adams, said.

```
$("#option-type option:first").select (myCompute);
$("#option-type").change (myCompute);
$("#tabelle").hide();
```

If I bind the function with `$("#tabelle").hide();`, the table is hidden from the very beginning. By changing the options to option1 the table is shown. How can I show the table when option 1 is selected and how can I hide the table when option 2,3,4 are selected?

Trying `option:first` results in an "unknown pseudo-element" error.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site. If you have multiple questions, they should be posted separately. Also, questions shouldn't contain answers; you can answer your own questions, so do so. While questions can (and should) be edited if they need anything (e.g. clarifications), they shouldn't be edited to ask a new question, as it invalidates existing answers and causes confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Ok, if I understand the revised question, the code now works as intended except when option 1 starts as selected.  (PS, the id's of the given code should be edited to match up.)

If that's true, then just change this line:

```
$("#tabelle").hide();
```

.
To this:

```
if ($("#option-type")[0].selectedIndex == 0 )
    $("#tabelle").show();
else
    $("#tabelle").hide();
```

---

In Greasemonkey, you can't set event handlers that way due to sandbox protection.  See [Common Pitfalls in Greasemonkey](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers).
Also, with jQuery, there are easier ways to select that element.

Something like: `$("#idname option:first").select (YourEventHandler)` should work.

Where:

```
function YourEventHandler (Event)  
{
    //YOUR CODE HERE
    //Note: Event is a variable passed automatically to all event handlers, you often just ignore it.
}
```

[Handy jQuery reference](http://www.jqapi.com/).

Comment: Hello Brock,

I hope I'm not looking totally noobish to you :(

So, I was able to  create a function and an event-handler which work fine. I edited my first post so that you can see my way and maybe(?) answer another question.

Comment: I don't know how I can make it up. 
Every bit helps me understanding it better.
Thank you soooo much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.selectedIndex` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980) to get which one's selected, like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("idname").selectedIndex === 0) { //option 1
  //perform the script
}
```

It's a 0-based index, so 0 is `Option 1` in your example markup, [you can test/play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/t73bN/).

---

I'm unclear from the question, but if you want this on the `change` event, it'd look like this:

```
document.getElementById("idname").onchange = function() {
  if(this.selectedIndex === 0) {
    //perform the script
  }
};
```

[You cant test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/t73bN/1/).

Comment: Hello Nick Craver, 

thanks for trying to help me. Like Brock Adams said I couldn't set the event handler that way. But ... you directed me ;-)